# Apply Hardy-Littlewood maxima inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,\mathcal M, \mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu(X)<+\infty$ and let $1<p<+\infty$. Let $f\colon X\to[-\infty,+\infty]$ be a measurable function such that for some constant $C>0$ one has

$$\mu\{|f|\ge\lambda\}\le \frac{C}{\lambda^p},\quad {\rm for\ all}\ \lambda>0.$$
Prove that $f\in L^r(\mu)$ for all $1\le r<p$.

I've tried to solved it with Hardy-Little wood maxima inequality (weak type estimate) but having trouble to solve it, can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $$\int_X |f|^r\, d\mu = r\int_0^\infty \lambda^{r-1}\mu(\{ x\in X: |f(x)|>\lambda\}\, d\lambda.$$

Comment: Shouldn't RHS be $$r\int_0^\infty \lambda^{r-1}\mu(\{ x\in X: |f(x)|>\lambda\}\, d\lambda.$$?

Comment: @Minglingmaster: Yes, yes it should. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much @Jose27@Minglingmaster

Comment: @Jose27 Sorry to say, I am still having confusion on this problem. Please give me few hints more

Comment: @user1002241: Hint 2: Break up the integral into two pieces. For one you'll need that $X$ has finite measure, for the other your hypotheses.

Comment: @Jose27 $$\int_X |f(x)| \, d\mu(x) = \int_X \int_0^{|f(x)|} \, d\lambda \, d\mu(x) = \int_0^{\infty} \mu(\{x \in X;|f(x)|>\lambda\}\, d\lambda.$$ Did you mean this? Are you using Fubini's theorem?

Comment: @user1002241: Yes, now apply that formula to $|f|^r$ and use the change of variables $\lambda\mapsto \lambda ^r$ to get the formula I wrote for $r\neq 1$.